Isssue with Accessing Nested OData Feed Outside Power BI – Nested Data Null in Browser/API Call
I am having trouble accessing nested data in a oData feed via anything other than PowerBi.
I have an OData feed, which I am opening via OData.Feed in PowerBi, opening https://xxxx/reports/api/v2.0/DataSources
Then I expand one of the tables ("dependentItems", nested data) via:
“Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "DependentItems", {"Id", "Name", "Description", "Path"...

image of expanded powerbi odata rows
This allows me to access the nested fields listed above. Which have data. It may also be worth noting that the first two rows are null. (in all fields not just pictured id/name).
-
When I navigate to the same URL, accessing this via a browser, follwing odata guide https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html#_Toc445374620
 https://xxxx/reports/api/v2.0/DataSources?$expand=DependentItems

image of odata via browser
The DependentItems is blank. Navigating to DependentItems/Name (or any other nested data) does not work either, likely because DependentItems is simply empty.
Both PowerBi and the browser is accessing the data via my windows credentials.
I have no idea what to try to resolve this. I was suggested to try postman proxy to record interactions but I do not have permissions to do this.
